# How to call stored procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, invoke

A stored procedure was created in mysql successfully but was not able to 
be executed in mysql.

How to invoke stored procedure in mysql?

Comment: There's plenty of tutorials out there on how to do this. [Here](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_Stored_Procedures.htm) is one. You need to `CALL` the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

The Stored Procedure is just that, a Stored Procedure. When you run it, all you are doing is creating the Stored Procedure.

To execute the Stored Procedure you actually have to call the Stored Procedure with it's respective in and out parameters.  Out parameters (op) should be preceded by an @ symbol.

```
Call SP_name(p1,p1,@op1,@op2);
```

When in doubt just go to [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html)